# Can I improve a resource in the same hex where I establish a city?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

In Civ 5, when I've establish a city on a hex, say containing "gold" resource, I automatically gain that resource without the need of improvement even (as long as I have the technology to use that resource).

It seems that this is not the case in Beyond Earth, furthermore- the resource on that tile is gone for good. Am I right, or what?

Comment: A little off topic, but fwiw, I usually try to avoid founding cities on a resource, because the improvements you build to begin harvesting the resource (like a mine) usually gives you huge production/food/gold bonuses, which you lose if you don't build the improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I've tested, in Civ:BE if you build an outpost on top of a resource, the resource is lost.

Comment: Correct, in fact there's a confirmation dialog that tells you so.